# Как вызвать ошибку понятную для COM?

Tags: c#, исключения, com

Как реализовать вызов ошибки, как com-объект?

Сейчас из JavaScript кода, создается:

```
var customObject = new ActiveXObject("NAMESPACE.CLASS_NAME");
customObject.GETWRAPPER.CallMethodHttpCom("METHOD_NAME");
```

Так вызывается C# метод. Из этого метода вылетает ошибка с каким-то сообщением. Мне необходимо, что бы при перехвате try..catch(error) из JS, я смог увидеть это своё сообщение.

Сейчас же я вижу:
[image: Содержимое объекта error]

Т.е. не то сообщения что я вызывал в C#.

Мне подсказали смотреть в сторону IUnknown, но к моему большому сожалению, не могу понять что я там должен увидеть.

Подскажите как реализовать или где посмотреть примеры для подобных проблем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня вот так работает

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace AxTest
{
    [ProgId("AxTest.Class1")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [Guid("177E405F-0C29-4FB1-B55A-D5324EDE1E97")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Class1 
    {
        public string Test(string x)
        {
            throw new Exception("Something bad happened!");
        }        

    }
}
```

JS:

```
<html>
   <head>
          <title>ActiveX test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
        <script type="text/jscript">

            try {

                var customObject = new ActiveXObject("AxTest.Class1");
                var res = customObject.Test("Foo");
                alert(res);

            } catch (ex) {

                alert("Exception: " + ex.message);

            }


        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Судя по сообщению, у вас исключение завернуто в TargetInvocationException. Чтобы получить нормальное сообщение об ошибке, вам надо его перехватывать и пробрасывать как свое исключение. Потому что в JS не достать InnerException.

Comment: Действительно, не заметил передается в обернутым в TargetInvocationException.